# How to run matlab function with spark?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, apache-spark

I am trying to parallelize a matlab program using spark (python 3.5), and I am having problems with that. 
I don't understand if it's an interoperability problem because of the objects' types that maybe, don't match between matlab and python, or if I have another intern problem.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import matlab.engine
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("reduce").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    x=eng.getListOfData()
    myrdd=sc.parallelize(x)
    object = myrdd.map(lambda x :np.array((eng.myfunc(x))._data)).collect()
```

This is what I get

```
Undefined function or variable '__getstate__'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 148, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 408, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 740, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 255, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 292, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  .....
matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function or variable '__getstate__'.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:.../mySparkProgram.py", line 20, in <module>
    EAPa = bandesrdd.map(lambda x : (eng.apa(x))).collect()
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 796, in collect
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2442, in _jrdd
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2375, in _wrap_function
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2361, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 464, in dumps
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 704, in dumps
  File "C:...\spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 162, in dump
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function or variable '__getstate__'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own problem for those who may encounter this obstacle:

With spark and using Python, in order to pass a certain task or function to the method 'map', the object passed must be serialisable. That's why we get the pickle error, and getstate.

In this case, it appeared that a Matlab engine doesn't respond to the condition just stated. So in order for me to do that, I just encapsulated the Matlab call in an external Python function, which I pass in the map method. This works perfectly!

Note: Keep in mind that these calls between different platforms, affect the type of the object handled in this process.

EDIT: 
This is the external function where I wrapped the MATLAB call:

```py
def map_func(x):
    import matlab.engine 
    import numpy as np
    intermediate = np.reshape(x,(1085,2560))
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    x= matlab.uint8(intermediate.tolist());
    result = eng.myfunc(x);
    eng.quit()
    return result
```

I did some reshaping and casting, to be able to handle the object type for the targetted plateform.